# How to print f-string (with `=`) path with only a single slash

Tags: python, f-string, repr

Once a while, it was attempted to print the f-string (with `=`) path without double slashes. Some might have implemented this already.

**EDIT:**

`print(f'{p}')` does print single slash, but since I am used to `p=` format, it is expected to achieve this as well. Backgrounds are that: when you encounter IO errors and stdout path and then copy the given path to explorer. But there are several manual steps to get rid of the double slashes.

```
>>> p='C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python39_86'
>>> print(p)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python39_86
>>> print(f'{p=}')
p='C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python39_86'
>>> print(repr(f'{p=}'))
"p='C:\\\\Program Files (x86)\\\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\\\Shared\\\\Python39_86'"
```

**Add:**
Following answers, but it is found that the following is not working

```
>>>print(FileNotFoundError(errno.ENOENT,os.strerror(errno.ENOENT),f'{p=!s}'))
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'p=C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python39_86'
```

Comment: `print(f'{p}')`  returns `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python39_86` ?

Comment: Yes, `print(f'{p}')` does return `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python39_86`. But not with `=`

Comment: Doesn't that answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

When you use the `=` syntax in an f-string, you [get the repr of the value by default](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals). To get some other conversion, you have to request it explicitly.

```
p = 'C:\\foo'
print(f'{p=!s}') # Prints p=C:\foo
```

Comment: Great solution (put `f` before quote). But can you please look at why the tidy string `f'{p=!s}'` cannot work in `FileNotFoundError`?

Comment: @MathArt That's a completely different issue — it relates to how a FileNotFound error is converted to a string, not to the semantics of f-strings. Ask a new question about that.

Comment: Thanks for instruction. The explanation makes sense. I will try to formulate the question to ask when I come to more similar situations.